# How to Implement Google OAuth?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0

Actually i'm new to Google OAuth, i referred as many resourceful URL's as possible but no where they gave a detailed resources of understanding of how to implement Google OAuth in the Java application that i'm building i.e,. with best examples. Can anybody share or guide through best URL's for implementing Google Oauth login in my GAE application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you went through this link or not but here it is - https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer

They have given a step by step description of the request and the fields which are a part of that request.

I had used HTTPURLConnection object to open requests.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the current steps to setup Google OAuth on Google's end:

- goto console.developers.google.com
- click on "Dashboard" to the top left
- click on "+Enable API" at the top left
- click on the Google+ API (near the middle of the screen under the big red "G+")
- click on "Enable" at the top left of the screen
- click on "Credentials" at the bottom left
- click [Create Credentials] button and choose "OAuth client ID"
- choose "Web Application"
- enter an appropriate name for the application
- enter the URL (do not put a slash on the end of the URL). Eg: http://localjmir.app
- enter the callback URL matching the GOOGLE_REDIRECT url in your application
- click the [Create] button
- copy the "client id" value and "client secret" value to GOOGLE_APP_ID and GOOGLE_APP_SECRET in your applicatoin